# Show data from related table in a data grid upon selecting a data grid row in WPF

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, entity-framework, datagrid

I have two tables, Equipment and Components. Each Equipment consists of 1 or more components. Right now I have a data grid showing the Equipment, with related attributes from a View in my database.

What I want is to have a second data grid in the same window, which will show the component the selected Equipment in the data grid contains.

So far I know that I can get a selected row using the SelectedItem property:

```
 Equipment eq= (Equipment )myDataGrid.SelectedItem;
```

But when should this code be run? I am using EF to map my DB entities to CLR objects, where I have included the component and its relation table as well.

When the user selects a row in the Equipment, of course I would need to refresh the component data grid with the new info, which I can do like this.

```
 myGrid.ItemsSource = myDataSource;
```

How can I get started on this problem?

I am using a view, that includes data from 3 different tables in my Equipment data grid, so the table set to the data grid ItemsSource does not have a direct relation with the component table.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by using getting the components and inserted them into the data grid when the SelectionChanged event on the Equipment data grid is called:

```
private void EquipDataGrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                var row_list = GetDataGridRows(EquipDataGrid);
                foreach (DataGridRow single_row in row_list)
                {
                    if (single_row.IsSelected == true)
                    {
                        EquipmentView selectedEquipment = (EquipmentView)EquipDataGrid.SelectedItem;
                        using (wiki_nolek_dk_dbEntities db = new wiki_nolek_dk_dbEntities())
                        {
                            db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
                            var equipmentRelation = db.EquipmentComponents.Where(c => c.EquipmentID == selectedEquipment.EquipmentId);
                            var componentsForEquipment = new List<Component>();
                            foreach (var row in equipmentRelation)
                            {
                                var component = db.Components.FirstOrDefault(c => c.ComponentId == row.ComponentID);
                                componentsForEquipment.Add(component);
                            }
                            CompDataGrid.ItemsSource = componentsForEquipment;
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Det valgte udstyr eksisterer ikke.");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your own reply's code to remove useless `foreach` loop.I don't know how `wiki_nolek_dk_dbEntities` works exactly, but I'm also adding `ToList()` to any `db` query result to make sure the result is a `List` and not an `IQueryable`.

```
        private void EquipDataGrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            EquipmentView selectedEquipment = (EquipmentView)EquipDataGrid.SelectedItem;
            using (wiki_nolek_dk_dbEntities db = new wiki_nolek_dk_dbEntities())
            {
                db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;

                var equipmentRelationComponentIds =
                    db.EquipmentComponents
                        .Where(e => e.EquipmentID == selectedEquipment.EquipmentId)
                        .Select(e => e.ComponentId)
                        .ToList();

                var componentsForEquipment =
                    db.Components
                        .Where(c => equipmentRelationComponentIds.Contains(c.ComponentId))
                        .ToList();

                CompDataGrid.ItemsSource = componentsForEquipment;
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Det valgte udstyr eksisterer ikke.");
        }
    }
```